# Why not my link on the mobile?

Tags: html, css

I have this site:

http://infine-traiteur.ch/

We have 4 elements on the first page (I put a picture to understand that I mean)

http://i57.tinypic.com/288silx.jpg

If we click on a particular image (the high resolution) everything works, if you resize the window and reach the mobile links these 4 elements only and do not understand why it works.

This is code HTML:

```
  <div class="row">
<div class="carouselspaceholder"> </div>
<div class="six columns">
<div class="cro_fpc cro_fpbig">
<div class="cro_backgroundmask"> </div>
<img class="attachment-fc1 wp-post-image" alt="front (3)" src="http://infine-traiteur.ch/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/front-3.jpg" height="340" width="465">
<div class="fptitles">
<h3 class="fptitle cro_accent">
<a href="http://infine-traiteur.ch/">Commandez-votre service traiteur</a>
</h3>
</div>
<div class="slidelinkspan">
<a href="http://infine-traiteur.ch/promotions/book-event-2/">Plus d'infos</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="cro_fpc cro_fpsmall">
<div class="cro_backgroundmask"> </div>
<img class="attachment-fc2 wp-post-image" alt="front (1)" src="http://infine-traiteur.ch/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/front-1.jpg" height="170" width="465">
<div class="fptitles">
<h3 class="fptitle cro_accent">
<a href="http://infine-traiteur.ch/">Nos partenaires</a>
</h3>
</div>
<div class="slidelinkspan">
<a href="http://infine-traiteur.ch/fr/completement-toque-2/">Plus d'infos</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="six columns">
<div class="cro_fpc cro_fpsmall">
<div class="cro_backgroundmask"> </div>
<img class="attachment-fc2 wp-post-image" alt="front (1)" src="http://infine-traiteur.ch/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/front-1.png" height="170" width="465">
<div class="fptitles">
<h3 class="fptitle cro_accent">
<a href="http://in-fine.dg-site.com/">Rejoignez-nous sur Facebook</a>
</h3>
</div>
<div class="slidelinkspan">
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/In-Fin%C3%A9-Traiteur/537179693032309">Plus d'infos</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="cro_fpc cro_fpbig">
<div class="cro_backgroundmask"> </div>
<img class="attachment-fc1 wp-post-image" alt="front (2)" src="http://in-fine.dg-site.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/front-2.jpg" height="340" width="465">
<div class="fptitles">
<h3 class="fptitle cro_accent">
<a href="http://in-fine.dg-site.com/">Suggestions de la semaine</a>
</h3>
</div>
<div class="slidelinkspan">
<a href="http://infine-traiteur.ch/menu-2/menu-du-jour/">Plus d'infos</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Can you help me to solve this problem please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Lines from **4627** to **4643** in your site.css file (Media queries for mobile)

Remove or comment this lines.